# get a particular property value using Linq to C#

Tags: c#, linq

I created a class with properties like this

```
public class Dependencies
{
    public string issueID { get; set; }
    public string status { get; set; }
    public int dependencyCheck { get; set; }
}
```

Now I created a method where i can use these properties.

```
private static void prepareIssuesList(string IssueKey, string JIRAtoken)
{
    Dependencies dpObj = new Dependencies();
    List<Dependencies> listObj = new List<Dependencies>();
    dpObj.issueID = IssueKey;
    dpObj.status = "open";
    dpObj.dependencyCheck = 0;
    listObj.Add(dpObj);

}
```

Now my question is, how to change the `dependencyCheck` property value. The `prepareIssuesList()` can called for multiple times. So i am adding multiple objects to Dependencies class. At certain point of time i want to change the dependencyCheck property value. How to do this. I think need to use the Linq to C#. ICan any one have any solution for this one?

Comment: which one do you want to change? all of them?

Comment: what do you mean, "change the dependencyCheck property value"? You just have to assign it... Linq has nothing to do with it

Comment: your `listObj` seems to be not stored at all, so each time you call `preapreIssuesList`, it's going to be a _new_ one, right?

Comment: No idea what you are trying to do... but you should name classes like that as singular (i.e. "Dependency") to make the code more understandable

Comment: This code doesn't seem complete.  prepareIssuesList() is creating a local list and never returning it or saving it anywhere.

Comment: @Vlad same thing goes for `listObj`.

Comment: @Klaus: you're right, just edited my comment

Comment: Why is this downvoted? How about we all allow the non-native english speaker to try to explain her/his problem first?

Comment: You can use LINQ. This thread might helpful for you
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq

Comment: @Groo, the point is not in language but in code.

Comment: @Groo I down-voted it for the same reason that I voted to close it for *not being a real question*.

Comment: Sorry all, it is not storing those values. I thought it may store. How to store those added values. I am not getting any idea.

Comment: Where is `preapreIssuesList` called? Can you show that code snippet?

Comment: I am calling it in another method. Very big to fit here. I just give you the method definition in which i am calling.                   internal static ChangeSetData getChangeSet(string issuekey,string jiratoken){ prepareIssueList(issuekey, jiratoken) }

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do something along these lines:

```
public class Dependency
{
     public string IssueId { get; set; }
     public string Status { get; set; }
     public int DependencyCheck { get; set; }
}

public class DependencyManager
{
     public DependencyManager()
     {
          this.Dependencies = new List<Dependency>();
     }         

     public List<Dependency> Dependencies { get; private set; }

     public void AddDependency(string issueId)
     {
         var dep = new Dependency();
         dep.IssueId = issueId;
         dep.Status = "open";
         dep.DependencyCheck = 0;

         this.Dependencies.Add(dep);
     }

     public void SetDependencyCheck(string issueId, int value)
     {
         var dep = this.FindDependencyByIssueId(issueId);
         dep.DependencyCheck = value;
     }

     public Dependency FindDependencyByIssueId(string issueId)
     {
         var dep = this.Dependencies.FirstOrDefault(d => d.IssueId.Equals(issueId));
         if(dep == null) throw new ArgumentException("Dependency not found", "issueId");
         return dep;
     }
}
```

Then somewhere in your code you could do:

```
var mgr = new DependencyManager();
mgr.AddDependency("ABC123");
mgr.AddDependency("ABC456");

//... some other stuff that makes sense

mgr.SetDependecyCheck("ABC123", 42);
```

Comment: +1 Although it would be worthy explaining why OP's code didn't work (because a new `List` instance was being created on each call).

Comment: @Klaus.. Thanks. Really I am feeling so much shy that i dont know that how to code like this.. really awesome.

Comment: @YSSS You are welcome. Just keep practicing and asking questions here and your skills will definitely improve with time.

Comment: @KlausByskovHoffmann the code what you present here also not storing values.

Comment: @YSSS hehe ok. I think you are not aware of when values are stored and when not. As long as the `mgr` instance is in scope, it holds all the values you put into it. When the `mgr` runs out of scope it gets "lost". Since I don't know the structure of your code, I cannot recommend how to best store the instance.

Comment: @YSSS DependencyManager keeps a Property called `Dependencies` that is used to store the `Dependency` objects.

Comment: What I done is, I kept in another function your second block of code. Means var mgr = new DepedencyManager().. etc Kept in prepareIssueList function.  I am calling twice in my program. Old values are not retaining.

Comment: @YSSS that is not the right thing to do. You need to have **only one** instance of the `DependencyManager`. You can't just create a new one and expect it to keep the values (how would that work, anyway?). In the class that has your `prepareIssueList` function make a property/field that holds the instance of the `DependencyManager` and use that instance in the function. The easiest way would be: `private DepencyManager myManager = new DependecyManager();`. Now in `prepareIssueList` you use `myManager`.

Comment: Where to wirte the private DependancyManager myManger = new DependencyManager(); ? In DependancyManager class?

Comment: If possible can you make changes to the your suggested code related to your suggestion!!

Comment: @YSSS **In the class that has your prepareIssueList function**