# How to view the values stored in a list?

Tags: c#, list, contains

I am trying to learn how to use lists in C#. There are a lot of tutorials out there, but none of them really explain how to view a list that contains a record.

Here is my code:

```
class ObjectProperties
{
    public string ObjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string ObjectComments { get; set; }
    public string ObjectAddress { get; set; }
}

List<ObjectProperties> Properties = new List<ObjectProperties>();
ObjectProperties record = new ObjectProperties
    {
        ObjectNumber = txtObjectNumber.Text,
        ObjectComments = txtComments.Text,
        ObjectAddress = addressCombined,
    };
Properties.Add(record);
```

I want to display the values in a messagebox. Right now I am just making sure the information is going into the list. I also want to learn how to find a value in the list and get the other information that is related to it, such as, I want to find the item by the Object Number and if it is in the list then it will return the address. I am also using WPF, if that makes a difference. Any help will be appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: you could use a linq query, check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1175662/647884).

Comment: if ObjectNumber is unique, then you might want to make that a dictionary (instead of list) with the `TKey` being the type of string to hold the object number.

Comment: I would have used a dictionary, but the user is going to have to be able to update the Object Number when the "product" is replaced or changed out.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way is to override `ToString` in your class and use [`string.Join`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd783876) to join all your records:

```
var recordsAsString = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
            Properties.Select(p => p.ToString()));
MessagBox.Show(recordsAsString);
```

Here's a possible implementation of `ToString`:

```
class ObjectProperties
{
    public string ObjectNumber { get; set; }
    public string ObjectComments { get; set; }
    public string ObjectAddress { get; set; }

    public override string ToString() 
    {
        return "ObjectNumber: " 
              + ObjectNumber 
              + " ObjectComments: " 
              + ObjectComments 
              + " ObjectAddress: " 
              + ObjectAddress;
    }
}
```

> I also want to learn how to find a value in the list and get the other information that is related to it, such as, I want to find the item by the Object Number and if it is in the list then it will return the address.

There are several ways to search a `List<T>`, here are two:

```
String numberToFind = "1234";
String addressToFind = null;
// using List<T>.Find method
ObjectProperties obj = Properties.Find(p => p.ObjectNumber == numberToFind);
//using Enumerable.FirstOrDefault method (add using System.Linq)
obj = Properties.FirstOrDefault(p => p.ObjectNumber == numberToFind);
if (obj != null)
    addressToFind = obj.ObjectAddress;
```

Comment: Amazing how just a few lines can teach a person so much. Thank you for updating your answer, it was very helpful!

Answer (score 2):

To display the items in a list, you can iterate over the list and get the information out of it.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (ObjectProperties op in Properties) 
{
    sb.Append(op.ObjectNumber + "\n");
}

sb.ToString(); // show this in messagebox
```

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do.

If you want to try to find some data, use this code:

```
List<ObjectProperties> Properties = new List<ObjectProperties>();
var result = Properties.Where(n => n.ObjectNumber.Equals('yourVariableHere'));
```

Comment: Awesome. I think this is what I am going to try in order to search for the values. Could you possibly explain how I could get just the ObjectAddress Property from this. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Assuming your ObjectNumber is the Unique ID you could do something like the following:

  var objAddress =  from p in Properties 
        select p.ProductName where p.ObjectNumber.Equals('YourVariable');

Comment: If you need a good cheat sheet = http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Answer (score 2):

`List<T>` class implements `IEnumerable<T>`, which allows you to use a whole bunch of very useful methods for querying the list.

I'd recommend taking a look at the MSDN documentation of [`List<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) and [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx). Go through available methods and see the examples. If you have any specific questions, come back to SO.

Here's how you can accomplish what you asked as an example:

```
string address = myList
                 .Where(x=>x.ObjectNumber=="A123")
                 .Select(x=>x.ObjectAddress)
                 .First();
```

Answer (score 1):

Once you have your list you can loop through it using a foreach loop and output the values that way.

You can also use linq to query your list and return the values you want.

For example:

```
    properties.Where(x=>x.ObjectNumber == 10).FirstOrDefault()
```

This would return the first record where the ObjectNumber was 10.

Let me know if you need more clarification.