# Technique to reduce load on server,while searching & comparing for particular item into large(10,000 entries) LIST object created at server side

Tags: asp.net, server-side-validation

I want to know that,

If we have **LIST** object created at **server side** which contains large amount of data entries like employess master data(**10,000**), & I want to give search option to search **valid** employee ID or name.

So I have tried to compare that entered text with that list of large entries in loop, which is obvious degrading performance.

So is there any option to better performace?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to find out whether or not the string is already in the list?  Have you tried using Linq?

Comment: Yes your right,but I haven't used linq. I have used generic list object. Firstly I dont know much about linq. Do linq will help to enhance performance? n Thanks for reply

Comment: Yes, Linq will help with your performance if you are simply looping through right now... This SO Question answers it for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq

Comment: thanks Brian P for quick replay n help.. I will try this one.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public List<Employee> SearchEmployee(string search, int pageNo, int pageLength)
    {
        MasterDataContext db = new MasterDataContext();
        var searchResult = (from e in db.Employess
                            where (search == null || 
                                  e.Name.ToLower().Contains(search.ToLower()))
                            select e).ToList();
        int pageStart = (pageNo - 1) * pageLength;
        var pageResult = from c in searchResult.Skip(pageStart).Take(pageLength)
                         orderby c.CardNo
                         select c;
        return pageResult;
    }
```

I hope it helps.