# Why does my LINQ query always return 0?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm facing a weird problem, I haven't programmed much with c# and only started recently, so I apologise in advance if the question is in fact just a beginner mistake.

```
int i = 0;
var index = from x in (
                from v in Category.Items 
                select new { Key = i++, Value = v }) 
            where ((MenuCategory) x.Value).id == menuItems[items.SelectedIndex].category 
            select x.Key;
```

I'm trying to get the index of a specific object in `Category.Items[]` (where the field id is a specific value, `menuItems[items.SelectedIndex].category`)

Comment: is it because the index of the column is 0? remember everything starts at 0

Comment: Right, but unless something else is wrong in the code the index should be 1 for the value I'm testing it with

Comment: If you need the index you can use method syntax and there is an overload of `Select` that will include the index in the lambda.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: `i++` stores the current value and THEN increments the value.  So if `i` starts at 0, the first call to ++ will return 0, are you expecting 1?  If so, use `++i` instead, it increments before storing.

Comment: check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17995757/521446

Comment: LINQ with side effects. That's an abuse.

Comment: you can get a list of (Value, Index) pairs like this: list.Select((Value, Index) => new { Value, Index });

Answer (score 5, accepted):

LINQ queries should not cause side effects like this. You can get what you want with method syntax and the overload of `Select`:

```
var selectedCatId = menuItems[items.SelectedIndex].category;
var indexes = Category.Items
    .Select((c, index) => new { Key = index, Value = c })
    .Where(x => ((MenuCategory)x.Value).id == selectedCatId)
    .Select(x => x.Key);
```

Comment: this worked, thank you. can you please elaborate on why it's not a good idea to have LINQ queries with side effects?

Comment: @user1494162: well, you have provided a good example. Queries are supposed to collect informations provided in one or multiple sources. If this query also modifies something it often depends on how the query is executed(f.e. if you have an `OrderBy` or `Where` and in which order they appear). If someone changes this logic ´he might also change the effect but unknowingly.