# Find string position in list C#

Tags: c#, string, list

I have a list `List<string> strList` where strings are added to the list throughout the program.

I want to be able to find a certain position or index of the list containing a certain string.

I've managed to check if a string that contains a certain text exists using this code:

```
if (strList.Exists(str => str.Contains("Chicken")))
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Found it");
            }
```

But I would like to find which position in the list this string has.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the index of an item in a list in a single step?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17995706/how-to-get-the-index-of-an-item-in-a-list-in-a-single-step)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `FindIndex`

```
 int index = strList.FindIndex(str => str.Contains("Chicken"));
```

> Searches for an element that matches the conditions defined by the specified predicate, and returns the zero-based index of the first occurrence within the entire List.

Answer (score 0):

Muhammad solution is working fine with me , i just needed to avoid case issues ,i used the below ,same code with minor change

```
 int Index = listOfStrings.FindIndex(x => x.Msg.Equals(msg, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
```