# use linq to find item in list of arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

I have a list of arrays with 2 strings in each array.  I need to check if the first string in each array matches a given number.  I am assuming that linq is the best way to do this.  I found a helpful SO answer here: [Find an item in List by LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq/1175662#1175662)
It states to find an item in a list do this:

```
string result = myList.Single(s => s == search);
```

From the comments, I think I want to use SingleOrDefault.  But how do I make it search the first item of each array in the list?
Here is my list of arrays:

```
List<string[]> shipsLater = new List<string[]> {};    
string[] itemArr = { item.pid, future };
shipsLater.Add(itemArr);
```

Comment: what do you want as result?

Comment: I want to search all of the item.pid for a given string, such as "9022".

Comment: Simplest would be `shipsLater[0][0] == shipsLater[1][0]` ;)

Comment: you still didnt answer my question, what should be the result? list of arrays? a single array? a string?

Comment: oh, basically just true or false, did i find it or not

Comment: What is with the down-voting?

Comment: 3 votes to close?  Seriously?  What don't you like?  Please make some comments instead of just down-voting and voting to close.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So you have a List of arrays like:

```
List<string[]> list = new List<string[]>();
```

Now each array consist of two elements, and you want to compare if first element is equal to your search parameter. You can do:

```
var query = list.Where(arr=> arr.First() == search);
```

This will give you all those element in the list which matches your condition.

From your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28861786/use-linq-to-find-item-in-list-of-arrays/28861820?noredirect=1#comment45989273_28861786):

> basically just true or false, did i find it or not

If you are only looking to get back a boolean result indicating whether the condition has met or not use `Enumerable.Any` like:

```
bool result = list.Any(arr=> arr.First() == search);
```

if your parameter is of type `int` then call `ToString` like:

```
bool result = list.Any(arr=> arr.First() == search.ToString());
```

Comment: There can only be one or none.  Can I use SingleOrDefault instead of Where?

Comment: @dmikester1, just to be clear, you mean there will be one item in the list which would match the condition ? if that is the case sure use `SingleOrDefault`, but it will return a `string[]` where first item would match your search criteria.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Dictionary()` for best performance result; if you want to use `string[]` use this:

```
string result = myList.Single(s => s[0] == search);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your initial array structure is problematic. Careful conversion to a dictionary suddenly makes the implementation simple.

```
List<string[]> shipsLater = new List<string[]>
{
  new []{ "pid1", "abc" },
  new []{ "pid1", "xyz" },
  new []{ "pid2", "123" }
};

Dictionary<string, IEnumerable<string>> lookupByPid = shipsLater
  .GroupBy(g => g[0])
  .ToDictionary(k => k.Key, v => v.Select(i => i[1]));

// now your lookups are as simple as...
IEnumerable<string> matches = lookupByPid["pid1"];
```