# Divide The Deck In Two Players

Tags: c#, list

I want to give even number cards to player 1 and odd number cards to player 2 . If any of you guys could do it that will be really appreciated thank you. I know how to do this with array, but I am not sure with list.

```
class MatchDeck
{

    private const int NUMBER_OF_CARDS = 36;
    private Random r = new Random();
    List<MatchCard> deck = new List<MatchCard>();

    public MatchDeck(){ }

    public void createDeck()
    {

        int[] number = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        string[] suits = { "R[]", "R0", "B0", "B[]" };//these are suits i just made up 
        // deck = new MatchCard[NUMBER_OF_CARDS];
        foreach (var suit in suits)
        {
            for (int num = 2; num <= 10; num++)
            {
                deck.Add(new MatchCard(num, suit));
                //   Console.WriteLine(deck[i++].toString());
            }
        }

        foreach(MatchCard card in deck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card.Number + " " + card.Suit);
        }

    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {

        Random ran = new Random();

        int n = deck.Count;

        while (n > 1)
        {
            n--;
            int k = ran.Next(n + 1);
            MatchCard value = deck[k];
            deck[k] = deck[n];
            deck[n] = value;
        }

        foreach (MatchCard card in deck)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(card.Number + " " + card.Suit);
        }
    }

    public void deal()
    {
        List<MatchCard> player1 = new List<MatchCard>();
        List<MatchCard> player2 = new List<MatchCard>();

    }
}
```

Comment: how did you do it with array?

Comment: If val % 2 = 0 its even else its odd...you can also switch your shuffle to orderby(() => rand.next())

Comment: If you can do it with an array, you can do it with a `List`.

Answer (score 1):

What you trying to achieve can be done by using a loop or Linq.
If you want to loop through your `array` or `List` the condition would be 
`if(deck[i] % 2 == 0)` for even numbers. The opposite for odd. But this is already mentioned in the comment of @misha130.

May be you want to read about the `Linq` possibilities that `List` offers.
Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq) that gives you a nice example how to extract values from a `List` according to a condition (like in your case). To get to know the class `List` and its methods please read the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx)
These two particular methods would be of your main interest in this case: [FindAll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/fh1w7y8z(v=vs.110).aspx) && [Where](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534803(v=vs.90).aspx)

Now you should have all the necessary information to solve your problem. Good luck. Comment if you are still stuck.

Answer (score 1):

I've refactored your code so to what you're after. The key part relating to dealing the cards is the `.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 0)`& `.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 1)` code.

```
public class MatchDeck
{
    private Random r = new Random();
    List<MatchCard> deck = null;

    public MatchDeck()
    {
        int[] number = { 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 };
        string[] suits = { "R[]", "R0", "B0", "B[]" };
        deck = number.SelectMany(n => suits, (n, s) => new MatchCard(n, s)).ToList();
    }

    public void Shuffle()
    {
        deck = deck.OrderBy(x => r.Next()).ToList();
    }

    public void Deal()
    {
        List<MatchCard> player1 = deck.Where((x, n) => n % 2 == 0).ToList();
        List<MatchCard> player2 = deck.Where((x, n) => n % 1 == 0).ToList();
    }
}
```