# LINQ search in 2d array by word

Tags: c#, arrays, linq

Is it possible to search in array by word using linq ?

Example:

My array looks like:

> AA BB CC DD EE
>
> BB CC DD EE FF
>
> AA BB CC DD EE

I want to return lines where first column is "AA".

I am using linq to sort my array by first column:

```
sorted = array.OrderBy(o => o[1]).ThenBy(t => t[1]).ToArray();
```

I try to create somethink like
[Find an item in List by LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq)

```
string search = "AA";

sorted = array.Single(s => s == search);
```

But it will not work for me beacuse I am using a 2D array.

I'd like to return an array like:

> AA BB CC DD EE
>
> AA BB CC DD EE

Comment: How namely array looks (in code, I mean)?

Comment: string[][] array= new string[3][5] { { AA,BB,CC,DD,EE}, {BB ,CC, DD, EE, FF, }, {  AA,BB,CC,DD,EE},};

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple `where` will do the trick:

```
var result = array.Where(inner => inner.FirstOrDefault() == "AA");
```

Comment: + .ToArray() at the end. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try something like that;

```
var newArray = array.Where(x => x.Length > 0 && x[0] == "AA").ToArray();
```

Also, you should consider the subarray length to prevent unexpected out of index error.