# C# Select From Json List Using Where Clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, webforms

I have a json list and I have a type named post. I want to use it for search.

I want to get a list or one object with a query. Is that possible ?

Example part of json

```
{
  "Post": [
    {
      "id":"22",
      "text":"Dream Big",
      "img":"a2ca3cf9-664e-4d92-80f1-df20e971b7c0.jpg",
      "catid":"12",
      "meta_title":"Dream Big Design",
      "content":"some text",
      "user_id":"5556",
    }
    {
      "id":"24",
      "text":"Handmade Resin",
      "img":"423233-971b7c0.jpg",
      "catid":"7",
      "meta_title":"Handmade Resin",
      "content":"some text",
      "user_id":"1256",
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to select id = 23 or name like 'handmade'.

I tried with this code but it did not work

```
string json = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path + "output.json");
var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();

Post post = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Post>(json);
```

Comment: Can you please give your JSON list sample?

Comment: can you share your code with us?

Comment: @dbc Sorry I added.

Comment: 1) Can you share the `Post` type and the query that is not working?  2) Does [Find an item in List by LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175645/3744182) tell you what you need?

Comment: Let me check second way @dbc. Seems can solve my problem. Thank you

Comment: @serdar - OK, unless I hear back from you that you need more specific help, I'll mark this as a duplicate of [Find an item in List by LINQ?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1175645/3744182).

Comment: @dbc yes it is answer. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can use JObject in the C# that can parse the Json object and then you can fire your Select query.

`JObject jObject = JObject.Parse(your Json object in string);`