# How to get the incoming access token in ASP.NET API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, bearer-token

I need to run some logic in an ASP.NET API action using the claims in the passed in access token. How do I get the access token? And later how do I get the claim value in the access token?

```
[HttpGet]
[Authorize(Policy = "PaidMember")]
[Route("GetVideos")]
public async Task<IEnumerable<VideoModel>> GetVideos(string topicId)
{
    var accessToken = ... // TODO: Get the access token here

    // Then something like the following
    var type = accessToken.GetValue("membershiptype") // This line is made up
    return await _service.GetVideos(topicId, type );
}
```

Comment: this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49768774/how-to-get-access-token-from-httpcontext-in-net-core-2-0) can be useful to you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the claims with :

```
HttpContext.User.Claims
```

See here for get a specific claim : [Extract values from HttpContext.User.Claims](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120968/extract-values-from-httpcontext-user-claims)

I suggest you to use the ASP pipeline with Authorization middlware if you want to check claims. See [Microsoft Docs - ASP.NET Core Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the claim value like this:

```
(User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity).FindFirst("membershiptype").Value
```

With this you do not need to get the original token

Answer (score 0):

you can go through the following link as a reference for your queries
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B2jDN53taDk&list=PL6n9fhu94yhW7yoUOGNOfHurUE6bpOO2b&index=23