# ClaimsPrincipal VS ClaimsIdentity VS Claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, moq, xunit

Have anyone tell the three concepts. I'm a little confused about them. And what are used for explicitly?

```
public void Should_Return_NotNull_When_Find_User_By_Updated_Email()
{
    var userDao = new UserDaoImpl(_context);
    var accessorMock = new Mock<IHttpContextAccessor>();
    var userClaimsPrincipal = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Sid, "1"),
    }, "mock"));
    HttpContext httpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { User = userClaimsPrincipal };
    accessorMock.Setup(accessor => accessor.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext);
    var userService = new UserServiceImpl(userDao,MockConfiguration(), accessorMock.Object);
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A ClaimsPrincipal can have many ClaimsIdentity objects.

Comment: Yeah，thanks, You're right. And a  ClaimsIdentity can have many claims, right? but I'm just not sure what it's used for? for example why ClaimTypes.Sid

Comment: [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50120968/extract-values-from-httpcontext-user-claims)