# How can I update specific element in List<T>?

Tags: c#, generic-list

I am writing a C# console application where I have a class Customer as following:

```
    public class Customers
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string UserID { get; set; }
        public int Pin { get; set; }
        public int AccountNo { get; set; }
        public string AccountType { get; set; }
        public int Balance { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
```

I am storing the customer data in text file as below ("Customers.txt"):

```
[
    {"Name":"Jack Willson","UserID":"Jack21","Pin":12345,"AccountNo":1,"AccountType":"Savings","Balance":2000,"Status":"Active"},
    {"Name":"Mary Poppins","UserID":"mary8912","Pin":67890,"AccountNo":2,"AccountType":"Savings","Balance":4567,"Status":"Active"},
    {"Name":"Harry Potter","UserID":"Harry45","Pin":12345,"AccountNo":4,"AccountType":"Savings","Balance":12000,"Status":"Active"}
]
```

I am reading this file as :

```
List<Customers> list = ReadFile<Customers>("Customers.txt");
```

I wish to update a specific customer field based on user input. If user leaves the field input blank then the field information remains unchanged.

The program will ask user to enter the `AccountNo` for which he wishes to update an information.
Then program will display each property like `UserID`, `AccountType`, `Status`. If the user doesnot enter any input for any of the property then information remains unchanged.
I was trying to save the input from user in `new Customer()` object but couldn't proceed to compare it or save it in `List<customers>` where i am storing the data from text file.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please show your attempts you have tried and the problems/error messages you get from your attempts.

Comment: Uhm, by trying? This is either an assignment or work: you should be able to do this yourself. SO is not a code writing service. We can help you with issues, but you have to put in the effort yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
var accountNum = 2; //I'm going to assume you get this from Console.ReadLine() and validate it.

//Find the customer with that account number...
var query = list.Where(c => c.AccountNo == accountNum);

if (!query.Any()
    Console.WriteLine("Customer not found.");
    
var customer = query.First();

//Now you can manipulate the customer object as you please
//In your situation I think you want to loop through the properties they can change and set them.
customer.Name = "Some new name";
customer.Pin = 1234;

//Save the updated information back to the text file however you currently do this
```

Hopefully this helps :)

Comment: Please read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/334823), especially the answering part.

Answer (score 0):

You can look into this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1175662/11927652) using Linq:

```
int acNo = ReadAccountNumber();
IEnumerable<Customers> results = myList.Where(c => c.AccountNo == acNo);
```

if you are sure that `AccountNo` are unique then `results` will hold just one element. You can update the first element if that exists.

```
Customers cust = myList.First(c => c.AccountNo == acNo);
cust?.Name = newName;
```