# Can you use lambda expressions and .find?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq

I need to create the exact same program as these but without using foreach. I need to use `.find` and lambda expressions. I  am trying to solve this problem for one week without any luck.

```
Action delljack = () =>
                {
                    
                    foreach (Gost x in list.listofguests)
                    {

                        if (x.name == "jack")
                        {

                            Console.WriteLine("There is jack in my list");

                            return;

                        }
                    }
                };
```

Comment: Maybe read the docs? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.find?view=net-5.0

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175645/find-an-item-in-list-by-linq

Comment: @JulyOrdinary That answer uses `single`. OP asks for an answer that uses `find`. Please reopen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do the same as your lambda without using foreach you can use linq:

```
    if (list.listofguests.Any(x => x.name == "jack"))
        Console.WriteLine("There is jack in my list");
```

To get more information you can read about linq here
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/

Comment: Thank you so much.